# 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base' has different version for the compile (16.0.1) and runtime (17.0.0) classpath

Tags: gradle, compiler-errors, syntax-error, runtime-error, build.gradle

Please kindly help a beginner on following error when trying to run:

Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base' has different version for the compile (16.0.1) and runtime (17.0.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

when conducting flutter run -v i get following:

```
[  +28 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +66 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 0b8abb4724aa590dd0f429683339b1e045a1594d
[        ] executing: [C:\flutter\] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[  +64 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] v1.12.13+hotfix.8-0-g0b8abb472
[   +8 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +43 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [C:\flutter\] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +47 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +92 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +53 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[ +142 ms] executing: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +27 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[        ] List of devices attached
           emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86 model:sdk_gphone_x86 device:generic_x86_arm transport_id:6
[  +13 ms] C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell getprop
[  +68 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +5 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +44 ms] Found plugin cloud_firestore at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3\
[  +14 ms] Found plugin firebase_core at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.2.5+1\
[  +11 ms] Found plugin google_maps_flutter at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\git\plugins-0a9d0c576a69f9b5d464ad811600e50a7b687911\packages\google_maps_flutter\
[  +15 ms] Found plugin path_provider at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-1.5.1\
[  +23 ms] Found plugin sqflite at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\sqflite-1.2.0\
[  +84 ms] Found plugin cloud_firestore at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3\
[   +7 ms] Found plugin firebase_core at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.2.5+1\
[   +9 ms] Found plugin google_maps_flutter at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\git\plugins-0a9d0c576a69f9b5d464ad811600e50a7b687911\packages\google_maps_flutter\
[  +12 ms] Found plugin path_provider at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-1.5.1\
[  +14 ms] Found plugin sqflite at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\sqflite-1.2.0\
[  +83 ms] Generating C:\allflutterprojects\rapidinhotest\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +33 ms] ro.hardware = ranchu
[  +64 ms] Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
[  +22 ms] Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
[  +18 ms] executing: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +57 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[        ] --------- beginning of main
           03-06 15:32:31.664 E/wifi_forwarder( 2123): RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
[   +5 ms] executing: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe version
[   +1 ms] executing: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 logcat -v time -T 03-06 15:32:31.664
[  +46 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
           Version 29.0.6-6198805
           Installed as C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
[   +4 ms] executing: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[  +36 ms] Building APK
[  +16 ms] [!] Your app isn't using AndroidX.
[   +1 ms]     To avoid potential build failures, you can quickly migrate your app by following the steps on 
[   +7 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[   +2 ms] gradle.properties already sets `android.enableR8`
[   +6 ms] Using gradle from C:\allflutterprojects\rapidinhotest\android\gradlew.bat.
[   +9 ms] executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[ +105 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[        ] openjdk version "1.8.0_212-release"
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
[   +3 ms] executing: [C:\allflutterprojects\rapidinhotest\android\] C:\allflutterprojects\rapidinhotest\android\gradlew.bat -Pverbose=true
-Ptarget=C:\allflutterprojects\rapidinhotest\lib\main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root -Ptarget-platform=android-x86 assembleDebug
[+3522 ms] :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE
[  +61 ms] :app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[   +3 ms] :cloud_firestore:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] :cloud_firestore:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] :cloud_firestore:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[        ] :cloud_firestore:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[ +322 ms] :firebase_core:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[ +114 ms] :firebase_core:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[  +39 ms] :firebase_core:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[  +16 ms] :firebase_core:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[ +135 ms] :google_maps_flutter:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[   +2 ms] :google_maps_flutter:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[  +38 ms] :google_maps_flutter:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[   +4 ms] :google_maps_flutter:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] :path_provider:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[        ] :path_provider:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[  +15 ms] :path_provider:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[   +6 ms] :path_provider:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] :sqflite:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] :sqflite:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[  +22 ms] :sqflite:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[        ] :sqflite:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] :app:preDebugBuild FAILED
[        ] 13 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 12 up-to-date
[        ] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +2 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
[        ] > Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base' has different version for the compile (16.0.1) and runtime (17.0.0) classpath. You should manually

set the same version via DependencyResolution
[   +2 ms] * Try:
[   +3 ms] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[   +1 ms] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[   +1 ms] BUILD FAILED in 4s
[ +356 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 4.8s)
[   +7 ms] "flutter run" took 5,786ms.
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:387:7)
#2      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:73:64)
#3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
#4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
#5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:139:18)
#6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:45)
#7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:709:32)
#8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:524:5)
#9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:32:15)
#10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:290:13)
#11     _DefaultProcessUtils.stream (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart)
#12     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:73:64)
#13     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
#14     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
#15     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:139:18)
#16     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:45)
#17     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:709:32)
#18     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:524:5)
#19     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:554:7)
#20     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#21     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#22     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
#23     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
#24     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
#25     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
#26     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#27     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:175:5)
```